# How to append the #id in tornado url?

Tags: python, tornado

I am currently working on the WhiteBoard application. I need to append the #id to url. it is same as http://awwapp.com/draw.html#1205febd. I am new to tornado framework. How to call this url to view. Please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`#1205febd` is not about back-end. It's a so-called `target`. When you have a link like `<a href="#1205febd">` on page `http://awwapp.com/draw.html` browser will append that hash to URL automatically (on click).

If you want to perform some actions on back-end depending on that hash you should definitely to get the id on front-end and use some RIA framework (`JQuery`, `AngularJS` etc.) to send AJAX queries to your back-end (`Tornado`?) and render the layout in browser depending on its response.